# Shortcut to rebuild solution in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

The shortcut to `Build` a solution in Visual Studio 2008 is `Ctrl + Shift + B`.

I would like to know the default shortcut to `Rebuild` the solution.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The command `Build.RebuildSolution` is not bound to any key combination in the standard profiles.  However you can use the following trick to invoke it

<kbd>Alt + B</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd>

This will navigate to the build menu via <kbd>Alt + B</kbd> and then <kbd>R</kbd> will select the `Rebuild` option

Comment: Very nice trick, and compatible between Visual Studio versions since it's a menu shortcut.

Comment: Can someone explain why they wouldn't have a keyboard shortcut for rebuild? It's a pretty essential feature

Answer (score 18):

Another way is to do this:

*Tools >> Options >> Environment >> Keyboard.*

Locate the textbox decorated by the 'Show commands Containing' lable.

*Type >> 'Build.Rebuild'
Select >> the rebuild type you want, you have two options to choose from.*

Locate the textbox decorated by the 'Press shortcut Keys' lable.

*Hit >> 'a key on your keyboard', i.e I used F6 for solution wide rebuild.
Click >> the assign button.
CLick >> O.K and to exit.*

Finally load up a test project to test out the short cut.

Comment: This helped me on Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: I cant believe, such an old post is still helping people. Wonders of internet!

Answer (score 10):

In my installation, there is no default.  I am configured for C#, it's possible other configurations will define this by default, but I don't think so.  You can see if there is a key assigned by going to Tools -> Customize, clicking the Keyboard... button at the bottom and typing "Build.RebuildSolution" in the Show Commands Containing edit box.  If there is a key assigned, it will show up at the bottom of the dialog.

Comment: This is what I did to map `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`B` to be rebuild.

Answer (score 2):

There is no default shortcut to `Rebuild Solution`.

In addition to the ways mentioned in other answers you can perform the rebuild by

- Create a [Visual Studio Macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4c73967%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) that rebuilds the solution and assign a keyboard shortcut to macro. The advantage of this approach is that you are no longer restricted by the commands provided in visual studio. You can create a custom operation like rebuild the solution, launch the application process and attach the visual studio debugger to the process. All this in a single keyboard shortcut!